# Django app [WARNING] Worker with pid 12276 was terminated due to signal 9

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Django application which runs on a linode server. I use a gunicorn for deployment. When I try to upload a large file of 40MB on the website (which is one of the functionalities). The website crashes: 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.2. When I view the error logs, this is what I get: [WARNING] Worker with pid 12276 was terminated due to signal 9. I already tried adding these lines to the server block of the nginx configuration file:
`client_max_body_size 100M; client_body_timeout 1000s; client_header_timeout 1000s;` 
and this to the gunicorn:

```
ExecStart=/home/jelleheijne/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/jelleheijne/NPS_data_processing.sock NPS_data_processing.wsgi:application --timeout 1000
```

to increase memory and time before timeout, but this does not work. Can anyone please help me solve this issue?